# Java BufferedWriter and OutputStream .close() method

Tags: java, outputstream, bufferedwriter

I'm new in java and there is a question about BufferedWriter and OutputStream closing.

I have some logic, where it is inconvenient to use try-with-resources:

```
public static void writeFile(String fileName, String encoding, String payload) {

    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    OutputStream stream = null;

    try {
        boolean needGzip = payload.getBytes(encoding).length > gzipZize;

        File output = needGzip ? new File(fileName + ".gz") : new File(fileName);
        stream = needGzip ? new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output)) : new FileOutputStream(output);

        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream, encoding));
        writer.write(payload);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            writer.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, i have to close all resources by myself. Should i close OutputStream AND BufferedWriter? Or it is ok to close just BufferedWriter?

Is everything ok with my code?

Comment: Why do you think it's inconvenient to use try-with-resources here? It seems like a perfect candidate here.

Comment: @vs777 I said inconvenient, because there is GZIPOutputStream/FileOutputStream choosing logic (based on payload size), which i wish to keep inside this method. So i don't know how to implement try-with-resources in this case. Could you show an example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Leave it to Java, let it handle it:

```
public static void writeFile(String fileName, String encoding,
            String payload) {
        boolean needGzip = payload.getBytes(Charset.forName(encoding)).length > gzipZize;
        File output = needGzip ? new File(fileName + ".gz")
                : new File(fileName);
        try (OutputStream stream = needGzip ? new GZIPOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(output)) : new FileOutputStream(output);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(stream, encoding))) {
            writer.write(payload);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is OK to just close the `BufferedWriter.` If you follow the Javadoc you will see that it closes all nested streams.

Answer (score 1):

If you close BufferedWriter its stream will be closed too but BufferedWriter and OutputStream both implements Closeable. So if you want you can just use try with resource to handle the close for you

for example :

```
public static void writeFile(String fileName, String encoding, String payload) {
    File output = new File(fileName);
    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(output);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream, encoding))) {
        writer.write(payload);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**  Added getStream to check if it needs gzip stream or no

**Note:** This answer is just an "update" of your code, i'm not sure what are you trying to do in general, so it may not be the best solution for your program

```
public static void writeFile(String fileName, String encoding, String payload) {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(getStream(fileName, encoding, payload), encoding))) {
        writer.write(payload);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static OutputStream getStream(String fileName, String encoding, String payload) throws IOException {
    boolean needGzip = payload.getBytes(encoding).length > gzipZize;
    File output = needGzip ? new File(fileName + ".gz") : new File(fileName);
    return needGzip ? new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output)) : new FileOutputStream(output);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but as you can see in my question code, there is a logic, where i'm checking size of payload, and based on it, choose GZIPOutputStream or FileOutputStream. So, i don't know how to use try with resources there. Is there a way?